# Nextjs with typescript

Tags: typescript, webpack, next.js, vercel

Nextjs with typescript show some error on deploy moment that does not show in development moment like that:

````
13:09:26    Failed to compile.
13:09:26    ./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/plugins/pages-manifest-plugin.d.ts:1:34
13:09:26    Type error: Could not find a declaration file for module 'webpack'. '/vercel/36bc1d70/node_modules/webpack/lib/webpack.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
13:09:26      Try `npm install @types/webpack` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'webpack';`
13:09:26    [0m[31m[1m>[22m[39m[90m 1 | [39m[36mimport[39m { [33mCompiler[39m[33m,[39m [33mPlugin[39m } from [32m'webpack'[39m[33m;[39m[0m
13:09:26    [0m [90m   | [39m                                 [31m[1m^[22m[39m[0m
13:09:26    [0m [90m 2 | [39m[36mexport[39m declare type [33mPagesManifest[39m [33m=[39m {[0m
13:09:26    [0m [90m 3 | [39m    [page[33m:[39m string][33m:[39m string[33m;[39m[0m
13:09:26    [0m [90m 4 | [39m}[33m;[39m[0m
13:09:26    error Command failed with exit code 1.
13:09:26    info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
13:09:26    Error: Command "yarn run vercel-build" exited with 1
13:09:28    Done with "package.json" ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Install the definitely typed webpack package, [@types/webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/webpack)

Answer (score 0):

As a bit of advice, for an easy and simple way to use typescript in NextJS. After `npx create-next-app your-app-name`, you can use this simple library `npx next-to-ts` to avoid error.

Answer (score 0):

firstly, you can install @types/webpack easily

```sh
npm install @types/webpack
```

NextJS uses Webpack, and this happens when you have incompletely installed project dependencies. First of all, install all the packages with the `npm i` command, and if the problem is not solved, see which packages it wants and install them one by one.

You may have a typo in the `Package.json` file and maybe it is not visible and check that you do not have a unusual character or typo